# Can't make nginx to serve on my public IP

Tags: linux, nginx, server

I am trying to setup a nginx server. I can access the content on `127.0.0.1:80` and `localhost:80` but not on my public IP (`xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`). Here are my configs:

/etc/nginx.conf:

```
user rud;
worker_processes auto;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =403;
    }

}
```

I have applied several tips found from web like adding my public ip (`xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`) to `default` file at `server_name ip` but it still doesn't work.

Answer for duplicate question https://superuser.com/q/841255/733877 and https://serverfault.com/q/361499/476613 didn't work.

Comment: What makes you think that your server does not listen on that interface? How did you test that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Simply doing `curl <ip address>` gives connection timeout.

Comment: Yes as @arkascha says; how do you know port 80 is open?

Comment: `sudo netstat -tanpl` shows nginx is listening on port 80. `curl localhost` shows the document but not `curl <ip address>` where ip address means my public ip address. I have nginx running on a different machine and `curl <ip adress>` gives the content of that server.

Comment: This could be a simple routing issue. How does that system you test from know the route to that servers external IP address?

Comment: How can I start debugging that? @arkascha

Comment: The `traceroute` utility would be my first step.

Comment: Also you could add your network topology to the question. It would help everyone here to understand your setup.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know enough about networking to post my network setup. I'll try to see if traceroute is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post results of the command netstat -tlupn, full line, the server may be listening on port but only for local address...

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/raw/S1GiXNiY @night-gold

Comment: The first listen should be all you need as you already include all IP, did you try removing the ipv6 one?

Comment: I disabled ipv4 and restarted nginx, still it doesn't work. Here is the output of `sudo netstat -tupln`: https://pastebin.com/raw/wPBLfiui

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forwarding the port from your network to your computer? I had this exact problem and it was fixed once I forwarded the port to the computer with nginx installed.